# office 2010 won't switch interface language

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

Office 2010 won't switch interface language. Windows 10 Pro 64 bit runs in English but Office is stuck in Hebrew despite fact that it is set to follow the Windows default, which is English. Closed and restarted Office app; rebooted the PC without any change. I can't delete Hebrew because I need that too.

[image: Screenshot of Office Language setting]

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of the Word Options>Languages window?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for adding the screenshot (next time respond in comment upon edit, so I'd be notified.)

You cannot switch to English because you just don't have English Language Interface installed at all. Setting it to follow the Windows Default works when you have two language interface packages installed, it'll follow the Windows Default language. Not if you do not have English Language Interface installed at all.

You need to install the Office 2010 English LIP (Language Interface Pack.) The problem is that they aren't any more available from MS themselves. Do you have office (I'm not asking about Windows) 32 bit or 64 bit? ([Here's](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24259/beginner-discover-if-youre-running-the-32-or-64-bit-version-of-office-2010/) how to check.)

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but current problem...

I just solved this on Windows 10 with Office 2016 with the help from the answer from @Yisroel Tech.

The Windows was in Spanish, and office was too until after an automatic update turned it into english.

In my case I cannot select the office display language, it will always follow the system language... unless, as Yisroel said, it's not available. I didn't know because on my interface since I cannot pick a language I cannot see which languages are installed or not. Since it was in spanish since the day it was installed  I never thought of it not being available.

You can download the language pack from microsoft here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f

Some visual aid. Pick your language from the drop down list:
[image: selecting disired language]

Pick the right version for your office installation:
[image: pick 32 or 64 version]